# How to add Script on Header of Specific Page

Tags: wordpress, header

I tried to add header on main page, but i don't understand how to do this on specific page.

My domain is abc.com and I want to add a script on header of specific page, like abc.com/about on wordpress?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please review the following and update your question according:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

open header.php file and add below condition

```
<?php
//slug name
if( is_page( array( 'about') ) )
{
?>
add your script here
<?php   
}
?>
```